# Move Canvas if Shape is outside of it

Tags: canvas, javafx, graphics, shapes

So I have this small line of code:

```
@FXML
private Canvas konj;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    GraphicsContext gc = konj.getGraphicsContext2D();
    drawShapes(gc);
}

private void drawShapes(GraphicsContext gc) {
    gc.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    gc.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
    gc.strokeRoundRect(160, 60, 30, 30, 10, 10);
    gc.fillArc(-30, 110, 30, 30, 45, 240, ArcType.OPEN); //outside canvas!
    gc.fillArc(60, 110, 30, 30, 45, 240, ArcType.CHORD);
    gc.fillArc(110, 110, 30, 30, 45, 240, ArcType.ROUND);

}
```

Which result is:

[image]

As you can see there are only three shapes visible although I have four of them. Since one of them has negative x value (-30) it does not show up. For that reason I added a scroll pane for the canvas but the result is still the same.